# Scala Factory Design Pattern,what is "loose" coupling?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I am studying about the Factory Design Pattern in Scala.One of the benefits of this method is Loose Coupling between Object Creation logic and Client (from http://www.journaldev.com/10350/factory-design-pattern-in-scala). How can we achieve this and why we need loose coupling at all? Can someone give some examples and explain this?

Comment: *How can we achieve this*. Can you elaborate on what you mean by this, the link already explains how to implement the factory pattern in *Scala*.

Comment: @CKing Yes,the example is ok.What I meant is that I would like to see more examples and explanations.

Comment: Can you define *more examples*? You want more real world use cases? That wouldn't change anything because the structure of the classes would remain the same and. What more explanation do you want? What did you not understand? If you want an explanation of loose coupling through factory pattern, that makes a fair enough question.

Comment: Basically you want to define how you create the object in a different place than were you use it - this way you can easily swap implementations, modify the way you create object in just one place instead of the whole codebase etc. BTW that whole example could be rewritten into just (higher order) functions and drop the `Factory` from name as it reeks of OO.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks,yes I have also noticed that the example could be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are looking for an example on Factory Pattern in Scala, you can find the usecase with some simple examples [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/factory-pattern-in-scala-design-patterns)

Factory pattern is more useful when creating API library classes (classes which can be used by other classes). Hope the below example will explain it clearly,

```
trait ContentAPI {

  def getContentById(id : Int) : String
  def getContentByTitle(title: String) : String
  def getAllContent(title: String) : String }


object ContentAPI {


  protected class ContentAPI(config: APIConfig) extends PageContentAPI {


  /**
    * get all content of a page parsing the page title
    *
    * @param query title parsed
    * @return all content as a String
    */
 override def getAllContent(query: String) : String = {

   var pageContent: String = " Some text"
   pageContent

 }

  /**
    * get only the content body text parsing the page title
    *
    * @param query title parsed
    * @return content as a String
    */
 override def getContentByTitle(query: String) : String = {

   var pageContent: String = " Some String "

   pageContent

 }

  /**
    * get only the content body text parsing the page id
    *
    * @param query id parsed
    * @return content as a string
    */
 override def getContentById(query: Int) : String

    var pageContent: String = "some string"

    pageContent 
  }
 }

class APIConfig(path: String) {

val inputPath = path

}

 /** Configuration object for the Content API */
object APIConfig {
  protected class APIConfigBuilder(dataPath: String) {

   def setDataPath(path: String): APIConfigBuilder = {
    new APIConfigBuilder(path)
   }

   def getOrCreate(): APIConfig = {
     new APIConfig(dataPath)
   }
 }

  def withBuilder(): APIConfigBuilder = {
    new APIConfigBuilder("")
 }
}

  def apply(config: APIConfig): ContentAPI = {
    new ContentAPI(config)
 }
}

/** Client Object */
object APIClient{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import Arguments.WIKI_DUMP_BASE
    val dataPath = "path"

    val contentAPI =   ContentAPI(APIConfig.withBuilder().setDataPath(dataPath).getOrCreate())

    contentAPI.getAllContent("Anarchism").show()
    contentAPI.getContentByTitle("Anarchism").show()
    contentAPI.getContentById(12).show()
  }
}
```